# How to insert variables in R twitteR updates?

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the twitteR package in R to update my twitter status with results from analysis. The static tweet function works:

```
library(twitteR)

sess = initSession('username','password')

tweet = tweet('I am a tweet', sess)
```

However, when I add a variable to display some specific results I get an error.

```
library(twitteR)

sess = initSession('username','password')

res = c(3,5,8)
msg = cat('Results are: ', res, ', that is nice right?')

tweet = tweet(msg, sess)
```

Results in:

```
Error in twFromJSON(rawToChar(out)) : 
  Error: Client must provide a 'status' parameter with a value.
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I get when I run bits of your code:

```
> res = c(3,5,8)
> msg = cat('Results are: ', res, ', that is nice right?')
Results are:  3 5 8 , that is nice right?> 
> msg
NULL
```

The problem is that `cat` prints strings to stdout, rather than returning them as a string.  What you want is:

```
> res = c(3,5,8)
> msg = paste('Results are: ', toString(res), ', that is nice right?', sep='')
> msg
[1] "Results are: 3, 5, 8, that is nice right?"
```